# Kotlin Android - Change app start up background color

Tags: android

As title, I need to change my app start up background color. Actually, is full white, and need to be #202030
I tried with

```
<item name="android:windowBackgroundColor">#202030</item>
```

in my style.xml but it's full black, no matters what color I set to this attribute.
Also, I can't use directly

```
<item name="android:backgroundColor>#202030</item>
```

because I will get also Cut/Copy/Paste background menu with this color and text in black

This is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#202030</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#1E88E5</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#202030</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#1d1d30</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#E0E0E0</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/TimePickerStyleLight</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/product_sans_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#E0E0E0</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#3399ff</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#3399ff</item>
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#BDBDBD</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please post your entire styles file, chances are good your base style is a dark style

Comment: Added my style file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `colors.xml`

add

```
  <color name="splash_color">#202030</color>
```

then in `style.xml` add `splash_color` to your theme.

```
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/splash_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

to create your custom color in Android Studio, you can add you color in past Values->Color->then put you line color that you want.
[step-one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNHt3.png)

Then, you can go in you xml background color and add in your layout, just as simple
[step-two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6qGz.png)

i hope that i can help, if this is not your aswer, comment here and explain more what you want.